# Anaconda Navigator fails to launch

Tags: anaconda

I have installed the Anaconda 3. When trying to launch the Anaconda Navigator, I just see a prompt (conda.exe) opening and closing but the Navigator never opens up. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set correct path in Environment variable. Make sure that your Environment variable is something like this order -
c://user/anaconda3/;c://user/anaconda3/lib/bin;c://user/anaconda3/scripts;

If the issue still exists try to reinstall navigator or update it.

- $ conda install anaconda-navigator
- $ conda update anaconda
- $ conda update anaconda-navigator